# Having issues setting up function for form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

```
<td> <label> Gender: </label> </td>
<td> <select> id="gender" name = "gender">
                        <option>Select a gender</option>
                        <option>Male</option>
                        <option>Female</option>
                     </select>
                </td>
```

Thats the form I'm trying to validate, and this is my javascript, but I can't see to get it to work:

```
function validateGender(){
                if("" == document.getElementsByID('gender')[0].selectedIndex){
                    alert("Please select a gender")
                    return;
}
            }
```

Comment: It's `getElementById` with a lowercase `d`, it's not an array, as ID's are unique.

Comment: And even the HTML is invalid, you close the select before the id ?

Comment: This is a very common problem called Form Validation and **everybody knows** that it should be done on the server-side. What if your user turn off the JavaScript? Opp, then validation is passed regarding his input! Stop solving wrong problem, and pick any popular framework for server side and start handling it from there!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    <script>
        function validateGender(){
            if( document.getElementById('gender').selectedIndex == 0 ){
                alert("Please select a gender");
            }
        }
    </script>

    <form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> <label> Gender: </label> </td>
                <td> <select id="gender" name = "gender">
                    <option>Select a gender</option>
                    <option>Male</option>
                    <option>Female</option>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" onclick="validateGender()" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55v9mboa/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateGender(){
                if(document.getElementById("gender").selectedIndex==0){
                    alert("Please select a gender");
                    return;
}

            }
```

```html
<select id="gender" name = "gender">
                        <option>Select a gender</option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                     </select>
                     <button onclick="validateGender()">validate</button>
```

Check this.